# scheduled event

Tags: mysql

what does this query do?

```
CREATE EVENT reset  
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY  
STARTS '2010-6-20 00:00:01'   
DO UPDATE `MY_DB`.`MY_table` SET `field` =  '0';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating scheduled events: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html

Every day at `00:00:01` starting from `2010/06/20` the column `field` inside `MY_table` will be set to "0"

Answer (score 2):

It creates a recurring scheduled event that runs everyday at midnight plus one second, starting from today, which runs the following statement:

```
UPDATE `MY_DB`.`MY_table` SET `field` =  '0';
```

This will set the `field` attribute of all the rows in `MY_table` to `0`.

You may want to check out:

- [MySQL 5.1 Reference Manual: `CRETE EVENT` syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html)

Answer (score 1):

Creates a recurring [scheduled event](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html) that will update the specified database's specified table's specified field to 0 in all rows every 24 hours, starting at 1 second after midnight on the 20th of June, 2010.